# Mass editing columns fields record via phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

can someone help me please with step by step guide?

I have database with about 50 tables.
I want to edit some table which has 39 columns.
In that table there are 94,000 rows.
I want edit only one column (named: featured) for all 94,000 rows by one action.
I want to change the record (from y to n). its enum('n', 'y') type if its meter.

I need it to be done via phpmyadmin-->sql.

How can I do it? What do I need to write in sql option?

Lets say:

**database name: abc**

**table name: profile**

**column name: featured**

Thanks,

Victor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `UPDATE 'profile' SET 'featured'='n'` in case you want to set all entries to 'n'. Otherwise you have to add a WHERE-clause, e.g: `UPDATE 'profile' SET 'featured'='n' WHERE 'foo'='bar'`

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I go to sql there are: "SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE 1". Do I need to remove it and write UPDATE profile SET featured='n'?

Comment: Thank a lot! It worked! :) but it is should be with '. UPDATE 'profile' SET 'featured'='n'